# textarea change dom event that works without losing focus, for example for pasting using a mouse

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent, jquery

I am creating a web page for translating texts piece-by-piece. The user is supposed to fill many textareas and press the "save" button when done. The save button is inactive by default, and becomes active on keypress, keyup, and keydown. This, however, doesn't cover the case when text is pasted using a mouse, by right-clicking and pressing "Paste" or by middle-clicking (middle-click pasting is common in X Windows). This pasting scenario is relatively common on the web page that I am creating.

The "change" event would work, but it's only fired after the textarea loses focus. Is there a way to get that mouse pasting event to be triggered immediately when the text changes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("textarea").on("change keyup keydown paste cut copy", function(e) {

// do something

});
```

You can attach any event, you want to. Cut, Copy and Paste. I added all of them!